# How do you replace a tripod leveling ball's tension bar?

Tags: tripod, equipment-damage, repair, diy

I've got a Bogen Manfrotto tripod ([745B legs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00076WQ2M) paired with a [701RC2 fluid head](http://www.adorama.com/Reviews/pwr/product-reviews/Tripods/Tripod-Heads/Video-Heads/Bogen-Imaging/p/BG701RC2-Bogen-Manfrotto-701RC2-Fluid-Head-Supports-9-Lbs.html)), with a broken part. I found the page for the tripod on the [Manfrotto site](http://www.manfrotto.com/mdeve-tripod-black-without-cc), and the [parts diagram](http://mediacdn.shopatron.com/media/mfg/2747/media_document/live_2/745B_20041029.pdf?1272346474) makes it look like I need the R745,2 part. I even found it for sale [here](http://www.manfrottospares.com/index.php?route=product/product&keyword=R745.02&product_id=227), but I have no idea how to get the nut and bold out of the locking handle.

[image: Broken leveling ball bolt]

It's been broken for a while now, and I'd love to be able to get it working again, and maybe pair it with a Glif or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand which part you are calling the locking handle.

Disclaimer, I have not seen one of these in person, this is just from the parts list, which are always very handy for repairs (they show how the parts are supposed to go together).

To my eyes, you need to remove two items. First, the broken stud that is left sticking out of the red part of R745,1, and then the matching broken stud sticking out of the ball R555,7.

The first is easy. Put the R745,1 in a vise and use a ViseGrip on the threads and twist.

For the second, I'd take apart the ball and base. Use a socket wrench on R555.05
with the ViseGrip on the broken stud.

Should take 5 minutes or so.

Comment: I was referring to R745,1 as the "locking handle". Thanks for the input. Once I get the parts in, I'll have to try what you suggest.

Comment: The key is to hold the locking handle from turning. The ViseGrip will bite into the threads of the stud for grip. It will destroy the threads, but you won't use them, that's what the replacement part is for.

Comment: I got the part in tonight, and all went well. It was very easy, especially with your input. The part of the tension bar that widens (just above where the old one snapped) fits a slot in the tripod's legs that keep it from spinning when you're tightening the lock nut (the toughest part, since it's a confined space at the apex of the legs).